# Word document corrupted or unknown file encoding

Tags: microsoft-word, file-corruption

I am trying to open a corrupted Word doc. I tried different encoding options. If anyone know of a tool that I can use.

Here is a snippet output in HxD ( Hex Editor )

```
°qÄ<½r5!™¾=§Œ¾Âúþ¹äUiÊ(Ž?Áu\[.Ôy°ä”pMSè
¦é´EW5ð]Ã®ÖzpÍgëªI£m?dÞÍ[ñøÇàÆ/ú¡ òi9uo'ëâp?.mì¬ƒâ0Î6…5
```

HxD screenshot of Word Doc file:
[image: HxD screenshot of Word Doc file]

Comment: Do you have any idea how it got corrupted? just a hunch; can you create a TEXT hex dump of the first AND very last 120 bytes of the file? (Just Curious)

Comment: DOCX files are basically ZIP files. Without a 'ZIP header', which is the case in your file, you will not be able to open it. Data in screen dump looks like high entropy data so could very well be compressed data. Any idea how it corrupted, what type of drive is file on? Asking because sometimes some 'corrupt file' at USB flash drive is for example result of file system corruption in which case file recovery is more productive than file repair.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a try of following method to see if it can help you.

Some text-encoding problems resolve when you use a new, blank Microsoft Word file as a container and insert the problematic document into it. From the Inset menu, choose "Object"->"Create from file", then select the misbehaving document and click on the "OK" button to bring its contents into your new document. The act of reading the document data to process the file-insertion command can force Microsoft Word to apply the proper encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Your dump doesn't even look similar to that of a couple of `.docx` files
of mine. Mine all start with this header, followed by a large block
of zeros :

[image]

Your header is not even similar, and really looks like some random
binary data.

Sorry, but I don't think that your document can be recovered by any
tool that I know of.
I think you should concentrate your efforts on finding
some backup of the document, even if it's not the latest version.

Comment: These might help get at least some level of undertstanding: https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/docx/ and https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/doc/ - if nothing else then at least a "too hard for me".

Answer (score 0):

I created a Libreoffice "Word" document containing "Hello World!" in the default font and saved it in .odt, .docx and .doc formats:

The first five lines of hexdump on these looks like this:

```
$ od -Ax -t x1z -w12 Untitled\ 1.odt | head -n 5 
000000 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 08 00 00 c1 63  >PK.........c<
00000c 4a 55 5e c6 32 0c 27 00 00 00 27 00  >JU^.2.'...'.<
000018 00 00 08 00 00 00 6d 69 6d 65 74 79  >......mimety<
000024 70 65 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f  >peapplicatio<
000030 6e 2f 76 6e 64 2e 6f 61 73 69 73 2e  >n/vnd.oasis.<

$ od -Ax -t x1z -w12 Untitled\ 1.docx | head -n 5 
000000 50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 c8 63  >PK.........c<
00000c 4a 55 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >JU..........<
000018 00 00 0b 00 00 00 5f 72 65 6c 73 2f  >......_rels/<
000024 2e 72 65 6c 73 ad 92 4d 4b 03 41 0c  >.rels..MK.A.<
000030 86 ef fd 15 43 ee dd 6c 2b 88 c8 ce  >....C..l+...<

$ od -Ax -t x1z -w12 Untitled\ 1.doc | head -n 5 
000000 d0 cf 11 e0 a1 b1 1a e1 00 00 00 00  >............<
00000c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >............<
000018 3b 00 03 00 fe ff 09 00 06 00 00 00  >;...........<
000024 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  >............<
000030 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00  >............<
```

... based on this, I'd say that; if your file is a "Word" document, then it is badly mangled, or not complete (missing at least a few bytes - or a block - at the beginning?).

Note also that https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/docx/ states that docx is a zip with a number of XML-files inside, and that is (always?) reflected by the first two bytes in the file being `PK` as in PK-Zip (I believe).

Attempting to decipher compressed data isn't that useful, before decompressing...
And as the obvious "PK" and therefore the compression header probably is mangled or missing, or the 'document format' isn't such a file;

One might wish to look deeper into this one instead:
https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/doc/

Comment: Thank you for the effort and reply. I will be trying a few other methods that hopefully work